# Difference between instances created with and without `new` in GNU Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

What is the difference between

```
Rectangle origin: 5@5 extent: 40@30
```

and

```
Rectangle new origin: 5@5 extent: 40@30
```

Comment: Friendly reminder to consider accepting one of the answers (or asking further clarification in comments).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Rectangle new origin: 5@5 extent: 40@30` creates a fully-initialized instance of a Rectangle (to be precise with all coordinates set to 0) and then sets its coordinates and extent with the origin:extend: accessor method.

`Rectangle origin: 5@5 extent: 40@30` has the class Rectangle construct a Rectangle instance with the given attributes however it sees fit. In the case of GNU Smalltalk, it uses the basicNew message to allocate the Rectangle instance instead of new [(see the source of Rectangle)](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=smalltalk.git;a=blob;f=kernel/Rectangle.st;h=6d316f052c94e2e98eddbff4b0137b57235d4a35;hb=HEAD#l51). That forgoes the "fully-initialized instance" state of the variant above: it skips any initialization and just allocates the memory (well, the GNU Smalltalk docs don't say so explicitly, but that is traditionally the purpose of basicNew). Then it uses the origin:extend: accessor to initialize the coordinates and extent of the new instance.

Answer (score 3):

It's a matter of style. The Rectangle class provides a facility method for creating an instance, so that you can communicate directly with the class and write less code. It's also a good practice as you create the rectangle object with all it needs to work correctly (this practice is called RAII, resource acquisition is initialization). If you have a look at the source of `Rectangle class>>#origin:extent:` you'll find something very much like

```
origin: aPoint extent: anotherPoint
    ^self new origin: aPoint extent: anotherPoint
```

So actually sending the message directly to the class o creating it manually and then setting it is in practice the same

Comment: I have a subclass `Rectangle subclass: SvgRect` and then it suddenly makes a difference. With `new` it works, without it I get `Object: SvgRect error: did not understand` errors.

Comment: @adius This is probably because of another distinction: in addition to #new, there is also a #basicNew and the latter is used by the #origin:extend: class method. https://github.com/bonzini/smalltalk/blob/b2b2166789b1eb0fb73ba594fabf3ccfd21cf03d/kernel/Rectangle.st#L55  basicNew does not invoke initializer methods, so your "did not understand" errors are likely because the additional state you defined in your SvgRect is not initialized when you used the class method to construct your SvgRect instance.

Comment: As @JayK says, the errors may occur because Rectangle sends `basicNew` instead of `new`, but also there has to be some other part of it. If I had to guess, I'd say that your SvgRect has defined an `initialize` method, so the problem is that using class side `origin:extent:` won't work because, unlike `new`, `basicNew` doesn't send `initialize` to the object. If that is the case, you may want to redefine `origin:extent:` in the SvgRect to the same I wrote in the original answer to avoid errors.

Comment: @JayK @melkyades So then can you tell me what I need to change to get rid of the `new` in https://github.com/ad-si/svgtalk/blob/master/tests/SvgRectTest.st#L15 ?

Comment: @adius: You'd have to write `(SvgRect origin: ... extent: ...) style: ...; yourself`, so the message #style: is not sent to the class but to the new object. Otherwise I see no pitfalls.

Comment: @JayK Ahhh … it's the difference between sending `new`, `origin`, and `extent` sequentially or sending directly `origin:extent`. Now I get it. Thanks, very helpful comment!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is important to note the **difference** between Smalltalk and other OO languages.

In other OO languages you have a construct called a constructor.  Which enables you to automatically run certain code when you call method `new`.

For example, in **ruby** you would do

```
# Class name   
class ConstructorExample  
    # A constructor  
    def initialize    
        puts "I'm now running constructor"
    end   
end    

# Creating Object 
ConstructorExample.new # upon which calling you will get initialized run automatically.
```

The output would be in your shell:

```
> I'm now running constructor
```

In **Smalltalk** you have to differenciate between `new` and `basicNew`.  (Sometimes even `new` is only alias for `basicNew` so you have to run `initialize` manually
or create class method.  The `basicNew` does not execute the initialize automatically, the `new` usually does (not all dialects!).

The above example could be then written as:

```
Object subclass:#ConstructorExample
        instanceVariableNames:''
        classVariableNames:''
        poolDictionaries:''
        category: ''

ConstructorExample>>initialize
    Transcript showCR: 'I'm now running a constructor'


"You would then instantiate"
ConstructorExample new
```

or

```
| example |
example := ConstructorExample basicNew.
example initialize "sending method initialize like any other method"
```

In both cases the output would be (in your Transcript):

```
I'm now running a constructor
```

The main reason for that, in my eyes, is that you can run constructor after some of your custom code if you have class method

```
ConstructorExample class >> run
    ^ self basicNew; Transcript showCR: 'Running before constructor'; self initialize; yourself
```

Then you would simply do:

`ConstructorExample run`

The output would be:

```
Running before constructor
I'm now running a constructor
```

### Now to your example

As *JayK*, *melkyades* explained the main differences I'll give more suttle differences (details) on those:

### First:

```
Rectangle new origin: 5@5 extent: 40@30
```

What it actually does it this (without the `Transcript showCR:`):

```
| myRactangle |
myRactangle := Ractangle new. "Creates an empty instance with origin: 0 @ 0 corner: 0  @ 0 and would execute initialize if there would be one." 
Transcript showCR: 'Current origin: ', origin asString, 'with corner: ', corner asString. "You should see the zeros"
myRactangle origin: 5@5 extent: 40@30
Transcript showCR: 'Current origin: ', origin asString, 'with corner: ', corner asString. "You should your custom point(s)"
```

What happens when you do `Ractangle new`?

```
Rectangle class >> new [
    "Answer the (0 @ 0 corner: 0 @ 0) rectangle"

     <category: 'instance creation'>
     ^self origin: 0 @ 0 corner: 0 @ 0
]
```

When you check the source code it `sets origin: 0 @ 0 corner: 0 @ 0` (notice the difference setting it via ...`corner:` and not `extent:`).

### Second:

```
Rectangle origin: 5@5 extent: 40@30
```

The source code:

```
Rectangle class >> origin: originPoint extent: extentPoint
    "Answer a rectangle with the given origin and size"

    <category: 'instance creation'>
    ^self basicNew origin: originPoint corner: originPoint + extentPoint
```

As pointed-out already there is a `basicNew` which prevents the any `initialize` constuctor to be run manually or via class method like I showed above.

What you could do it rewrite it if you needed.  You would create your own rectangle class which would inherit it from Rectangle and rewrite it there.

For example:

```
Rectangle subclass:#ApplicationRectangle
        instanceVariableNames:''
        classVariableNames:''
        poolDictionaries:''
        category: ''
```

where you would define:

```
ApplicationRectangle class >> origin: originPoint extent: extentPoint
    "Answer a rectangle with the given origin and size"

    <category: 'instance creation'>
    ^self new origin: originPoint corner: originPoint + extentPoint
```

You would then call it:

```
ApplicationRectangle origin: 5@5 extent: 40@30
```